# Android Service How To Stop After Processing Is Complete

Tags: android, android-service

I have created a service that runs various tasks by calling methods, such as toggling wifi, sending a message etc.
It only runs one task at a time, and after that I want it to close the service.

Is there a way to check if the service has completed its processing and then shut down the service?

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396944/android-background-service-with-task-queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service knows when the service “has completed its processing”, so the service can stop itself via

```
stopSelf()
```

Or, better yet, use

```
IntentService
```

instead of

```
Service
```

This gives you a background thread (which you may need, depending upon the work that you are trying to do) and will automatically stop itself when there is no more work to be done.(Reference[1](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=117223))

[Reference](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=117223)